# Change UINavigationItem accessibility elements order

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UINavigationBar which contains 3 parts:
titleView (which is UISearchBar)
leftBarButtonItems
rightBarButtonItems

when the voice-over is on, the search bar will be the first one to be focused. 
which is not confirmed to the left to right order we are familiar with.

I tried to set UINavigationItem's accessibilityElements, but it still will highlight the searchBar first. assume because, inside the UINavigationItem, the `titleView` is the first subView.

any ideas on how to change the order, thanks~

[image]

Comment: Did you solve your title View problem? 

Comment: not yet,my case is I customed the left and right item of this navgationItem, when I set the titleView be searchBar it will focus the searchbar first when voice over is on

Comment: Have you consulted the examples provided in the different sheets dealing with the navigation bar in the site I mentioned in my answer to use VoiceOver with these items?

Comment: I may be wrong but I understood your question only dealt with the search bar introduced in a navigation bar. If you have customized the right and left items, I think it's a complete different problem that another question with detailed information should highlight to get the most accurate answer with VoiceOver. 

Comment: Thanks @XLE_22, so my issue is I don't use the default back button for the navigationBar, it is not the same behavior as you described. I found that the navigationController.navgationBar.accessibilityElements will always be
 [searchBar, _navigationBarButton, _navigationBarButton] for my case even I change the sequence manually.

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas on how to change the order?

I assume your problem deals with the **way you added the search bar** in the navigation bar.

I created a blank project as follows:
[image]

The code snippet hereafter is an example of adding a search bar as the title view:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let search = UISearchBar()
        search.showsCancelButton = true
        search.delegate = self

        self.navigationItem.titleView = search
    }
}
```

The result with VoiceOver on gives rise to the following screenshots: 
[image]

Following this rationale, **you have the VoiceOver initial reading order from left to right in the navigation bar**.

I suggest to take a look at [this site](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#navigation-bar) if further information is needed about a11y in the navigation bar and especially if you want to make a specific reading order.